# Unable to authenticate on proxy with SoapUI

Tags: authentication, proxy, soapui

In a SoapUI I try to access a web service through a proxy. I logged into Windows as a user authorized on the proxy, then in SoapUI in a preferences I specified proxy name and port.
When I try to execute web service I get "not authorized" from proxy. After that if I specify endpoint url in a browser, and then again run service in SoapUI everything is ok.
Why SoapUI not authenticate on proxy?
Thank you for your help.